# What are these kind of assemble-able "Erector" sets generally known as or called?

Tags: metal, aluminum

What are these kind of "Erector Sets" generally known as?

I know this is based on "Aluminium Sections". I was wondering if there is a class of products/ companies in the space that are called "something" and not only one of them.

**Origin:**

I had some DIY ideas I wanted to execute, but found the Wood work/ Metal-welding and drilling pathways a bit more hard core and cumbersome and not easy to disassemble-reassemble nor very light weight.

Someone suggested looking at a certain site/ brand (not promoting them as I am a consumer who likes the mechanism but would like to find other options in the space as these do not seem to be available where I am in Asia right now).

Is there a general name/ categorization or "what they are called" in common terms so that I can google and/ or ask around to find their availability?

Not sure if I should link to them but here is URL and a little about them.

**T-slotted Aluminum framing system** is the only term/ word I could come up with from their material.  **Is there a industry/ general set of terms/ names for it?**

http://www.8020.net

> 80/20 is a **T-slot aluminum  building system** you can use  to
>   construct virtually anything.  When you think of 80/20 think  of “an
>   erector set” for adults.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are usually just called T slot aluminum extrusions.

The 80/20 one is by far the most common style but now there are alternative standards created in the past few years such as

[MakerBeam http://amzn.to/2h2F9hq](http://amzn.to/2h2F9hq)

[OpenBeam http://amzn.to/2h1Tyui](http://amzn.to/2h1Tyui)

```
80/20 profiles
10 series   1" 
15 series   1.5"
20 series   20 mm  
25 series   25 mm  
30 series   30 mm  
40 series   40 mm  
45 Series   45 mm
```

Maker Beam 10 mm
[image]

Maker Beam XL 15 mm
[image]

Open Beam 15 mm
[image]

Comment: This 8020 is just the name of company. Thanks for responding - It was nice to see the products. I'd love to research the "variety" & standards instead - That would be great. Can you highlight a reference for all the "standards" in this space?

Comment: / I was hoping you could expand on the "standards" part of this space?

Comment: Are these alternative standards created by these companies or some organization/ body that has set some that are used by many manufacturers across a region or industry?

Comment: ^ ?? Thoughts/ expand on the above please?

Comment: Every manufacturer creates their own flavor of T-slot framing, there is no real universal industry standard for these things. Though I think almost all commercial usage of T-slot framing are using the 80/20 designed profiles.